# WebView not loading URL

Tags: android, webview

I want to load a web page in my webView.

Tried placing the `webView.loadurl("")` in `AsyncTask`'s `doinbackground` / `onpostexecute`
and in the `onresume`.

The url is correct but nothing happens it just shows a white page. In the android manifest file internet access is enabled.

What else needs to be done to load a webview?
The application does not crash or show any error.
In my emulator I set the proxy with my user name and password.

Here is the code I use to load the URL:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientSubClass());
webView.loadUrl(promoURL);
```

Comment: webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientSubClass());webView.loadUrl(promoURL);

Comment: promourl contains the string url

Comment: is the promo url like String promourl = "www.something.com";

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to check what callbacks your `webViewClient` is getting. I'm guessing that the site requests an authentication, so override `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` and do something like this

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
        HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onReceivedHttpAuthRequest"));
        handler.proceed(username, password);
    }
```

Or if the authentication isn't the problem you can always overide `onReceivedSslError` to see if there is some certificate problem.

As the initial step though, I would recommend you to use the browser to see if you can load the page. I'm having some trouble with an https site that requires authentication, I enter my credentials and the site can't load(this is on android 2.3)

Answer (score 1):

```
myVideoView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myVideoView.setWebViewClient(new  WebViewClientSubClass());
        myVideoView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myVideoView.setPersistentDrawingCache(0);
        myVideoView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        myVideoView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
           myVideoView.loadUrl(promoUrl);
```

try this should work and also check  whether it opens with **https** in normal browser.